# What is the relation between observables (as defined in the measure-theoretic framework) and POVMs?

Tags: mathematics, measurement, terminology-and-notation, povm

A [POVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM) is typically defined as a collection of operators $\{\mu(a)\}_{a\in\Sigma}$ with $\mu(a)\in\mathrm{Pos}(\mathcal X)$ positive operators such that $\sum_{a\in\Sigma}\mu(a)=I$, where I take here $\Sigma$ to be some finite set and $\mathcal X$ some vector space (using the notation from [Watrous' TQI](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/TQI/)).

On the other hand, when discussing *observables* in a measure-theoretic framework, given a nonempty set $\Omega$, a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ on $\Omega$ (in other words, given a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal F)$), and denoting with $\mathcal E(\mathcal X)$ the set of *effects* on the space $\mathcal X$, that is, the set of Hermitian operators $E$ such that $0\le E\le I$, we say that a mapping $\mathrm A:\mathcal F\to\mathcal E(\mathcal X)$ is an *observable* if, for any state $\psi\in\mathcal X$, the function
$$\mathcal F\ni X\mapsto \langle \psi|\mathrm A(X)\psi\rangle\in\mathbb R$$
is a probability measure. Here I'm taking definition and notation from [Heinosaari et al. (2008)](https://arxiv.org/abs/0811.0783).
In other words, $\mathrm A$ is an observable iff, for all $\psi\in\mathcal X$, the triple $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathrm A_\psi)$ is a probability space, with $\mathrm A_\psi$ defined as $\mathrm A_\psi(X)=\langle \psi|\mathrm A(X)\psi\rangle$.

I'm trying to get a better understanding of how these two different formalisms match.
In particular, an *observable* as thus defined is closer to a POVM than an "observable" as usually defined in physics (which is just a Hermitian operator), right?

Are these *observables* equivalent to POVMs? That is, does any such *observable* correspond to a POVM, and *vice versa*?

I can see that a POVM can be thought of as/is the map $\mu:\Sigma\to\mathrm{Pos}(\mathcal X)$, which then extends to a map $\tilde\mu:2^{\Sigma}\to\mathrm{Pos}(\mathcal X)$ such that $\tilde\mu(2^\Sigma)=1$, which is then an *observable*.
However, I'm not sure whether any *observable* also corresponds to such a POVM.

Comment: As far as i understand, wikipedia's POVM definition and this definition of an observable are the same.

Comment: well, in one case you only impose $\mu(a)\ge0$ and $\sum_a \mu(a)=I$, while in the other you ask for $F$ s.t. $F(\Omega)=I$ and $\mathcal F\ni E\mapsto \langle F(E)\psi|\psi\rangle$ is a non-negative countably additive measure on $\mathcal F$ for all $\psi$. I guess the question is pretty much why these are equivalent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two definitions define the same concept: the POVM measurement. The *observable* definition is how POVM is defined for use in the case of infinite index set and dimension (see e.g. [POVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POVM)) and *POVM* definition in the question is how it is simplified for use in the finite case. If you are working in finite dimensions, the two constructions are equivalent.

---

**POVM from observable**

We will construct a POVM $\{\mu(a)\}_{a\in\Sigma}$ from the observable $A: \mathcal{F} \to \mathcal{E}(\mathcal{X})$. Begin by choosing a finite $\Sigma \subset \mathcal{F}$ such that $\cup_{a\in\Sigma}a = \Omega$ and $a \cap b = \emptyset$ for every $a, b\in\Sigma$. This serves as the index set for the POVM and establishes the connection between the two definitions. Define

$$
\mu(a) := A(a).
$$

Note that this defines valid POVM elements because $0 \le A(X) \le I$ for every $X\in\mathcal{F}$ and

$$
\sum_{a\in\Sigma} \mu(a) = \sum_{a\in\Sigma} A(a) = A\left(\bigcup_{a\in\Sigma} a\right) = A(\Omega) = I
$$

where in the second equality we used $\sigma$-additivity of $A_\psi$ for every $|\psi\rangle$ and in the last step we used the fact that $A_\psi$ is a probability measure for every $|\psi\rangle$.

---

**Observable from POVM**

(This merely fills in some details in the construction you sketched in the question.)

We will construct an observable from the POVM $\{\mu(a)\}_{a\in\Sigma}$. Let $\Omega = \Sigma$ and $\mathcal{F} = \mathcal{P}(\Sigma)$. For $X\in\mathcal{F}$ define

$$
A(X) := \sum_{a\in X}\mu(a)
$$

where we are using the fact that $X$ is finite. Note that the right-hand side is a valid effect. We need to show that for every $|\psi\rangle$, $A_\psi$ is a probability measure. It is clear that for every $X\in\mathcal{F}$, $A_\psi(X) \in [0, 1]$ and $A_\psi(\emptyset) = 0$. Now, $\mathcal{F}$ is finite, because $\Omega$ is finite. Thus, to show $\sigma$-additivity we just need to show additivity. Let $X_{i=1,\dots,k}$ be a collection of disjoint subsets of $\Omega$, then

$$
A_\psi\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^k X_i\right) = \sum_{a\in\cup_{i=1}^k X_i} \mu_\psi(a) = \sum_{i=1}^k \sum_{a\in X_i} \mu_\psi(a) = \sum_{i=1}^k A_\psi(X_i)
$$

where $\mu_\psi(a) = \langle\psi|\mu(a)\psi\rangle$ and in the second equality we used the fact that $X_i$ are disjoint.

---

**Remark:** Note that the definition of observable appears to be more flexible: it doesn't just give rise to a single POVM. Instead, every partitioning of $\Omega$ using the elements of the $\sigma$-algebra gives rise to a potentially different POVM. However, this fact corresponds to the trivial observation that you can obtain a new POVM by grouping and adding elements of a given POVM.

Comment: ah, I ended up self-answering at the same time you answered. I like this one better though, thanks. Regarding the last remark: doesn't the "added flexibility" just amount to being able to write sums $\sum_{a\in Y}\mu(a)$ as some (additive) function acting directly on $Y$? I'm not sure that I see any material advantage in this (apart from noticing that the resulting object is a measure, and therefore being able to use known results from measure theory, I guess)

Comment: Thanks! Heh, perhaps I should have polished less and just send the key fact that the *observable* definition hides the index set whereas the POVM definition makes it explicit. It turns out the index set is just some partitioning of $\Omega$ using the sets in the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I wrote the remark to explain why in the "POVM from observable" construction we do not end up with one-to-one mapping from observable to POVM. That flexibility really corresponds to the flexibility we already have in the finite *POVM* definition, so I agree it isn't any real new advantage to the *observable* definition.

Comment: Regarding the ability to deploy measure theory - that is key! AFAIK, the motivation behind the *observable* definition is to enable its use in the infinite case. Measure theory provides tools to do that. The concepts such as $\sigma$-algebra and $\sigma$-additivity capture the sort of "tamed" infinity which we can work with and still end up with a reasonable concept of observable in the infinite case.

Answer (score 1):

Upon some more reflection, the answer is probably as follows.

Let $\mathrm A$ be an observable according to the definition in the question, and assume $\Omega$ is finite. Then any $X\in\mathcal F$ is also some finite subset of $\Omega$. By definition of observable, we require the mapping $\mathrm A_\psi$ to be additive and non-negative, and therefore
$$\langle \psi|\mathrm A(X)\psi\rangle = \sum_{\omega\in X}\langle \psi|\mathrm A(\{\omega\})\psi\rangle \ge0.$$
It follows that, for any $\omega\in\Omega$, the operator $\mathrm A(\{\omega\})$ is positive semi-definite: $\mathrm A(\{\omega\})\ge0$.

Furthermore, asking $\mathrm A_\psi$ to be a *probability* measure also means that $\mathrm A_\psi(\Omega)=1$ for all $\psi$, that is, $\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}A(\{\omega\})$ to be an operator whose expectation value is $1$ on any state $\psi$. This implies $\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}A(\{\omega\})=I$.

It follows that, defining $\mu(\omega)\equiv A(\{\omega\})$, we get the definition of POVM as collection of positive semi-definite operators summing to the identity.

Comment: This construction is correct. The other answer is a generalization, based on the fact that all finite partitionings of $\Omega$ - not just the one that breaks it up into the single-element sets $\{\omega\}$ - yield valid POVMs. This allows us to drop the assumption that $\Omega$ is finite.

Comment: @AdamZalcman good point. Thanks for the remark